# How do I pass JavaScript variables to PHP in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am developing a recriment software and in Yii2 framework application form I want to check if applicant has already applied for same job using 'passport no', my form looks like

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'cnic')->textInput(['type' => 'number']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Save and Continue', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and I am unable to get the cnic value in php. my Javascript code is.

```
$('#applications-cnic').change(function(){
    var data = $(this).val();

    var validation = <?= $model->checkCNIC($postid, '<script>data</script>'?>. <?= ) ?>;
    alert(validation);
    if (validation == 'data_exist') {
        alert("You have already applied for this job, use your tracking ID to check your applicaiton or contact HR");
    }
    
});
```

it is not working and I am unable to pass this value I get from javascript to my php function.

```
public function checkCNIC($value , $cnic)
{   

    $query=  Applications::find()
                ->where(['post_id' => $value])
                ->andWhere(['cnic' => $cnic])
                ->all();
                
        if ($query) {
            return 'data_exist';
        }
        else
            return 'no_data';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use ajax request sending your data (`$('#applications-cnic').val()`) and check it in your action with current php function?

Comment: Yes I have done using Ajax but but the way you mentioned because I want to call a php function and pass 2 variables stored in javascript variable, So I made a Ajax validation function using 'validationUrl' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/applications/validateform'),

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the recommended solution. You can still use javascript inside php using `document.writeln`

```
'<script>document.writeln(data)</script>`
```